# call service method from a controller following correct factory patterns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, factory-pattern

I have the following class

```
class EvaluateService
  def initialize
  end

  def get_url
  end

  def self.evaluate_service
    @instance ||= new
  end
end

class CheckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    get_url = EvaluateService.get_url
  end
end
```

The problem here is that i know that i can do `evaluate_service = EvaluateService.new` and use the object `evaluate_service.get_url` and it will work fine but i also know that some frown upon the idea of initializing the service object this way and rather there is a way of initializing it via a call, send method in the service class.

Just wondering how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
class Evaluate
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def self.call(foo)
    new(foo).call
  end

  def call
    url
  end

  private

  def url
    # Implement me
  end
end
```

Now you can do this in your controller:

```
class CheckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url = Evaluate.call(params)
  end
end
```

The reason some prefer `#call` as the entry point is that it's polymorphic with lambdas. That is, anywhere you could use a lambda, you can substitute it for an instance of `Evaluate`, and vice versa.

Comment: This is, essentially, how I do it. But, could you please expand on your comment that it's "polymorphic with lambdas"?

Comment: I added a short addition, but if you don't know what polymorphism is, you should go and learn about it. It's one of the most fundamental concepts of Ruby.

Comment: Thank you! I think, perhaps, I've been doing 'polymorphism with lambas' for a long while now without knowing it had an actual name. Learn something new every day. Again, thank you for your thoughtful response.

Comment: This approach seems to work best if you have one single method from the service that you want to call.  I have a service file with several different methods that need to be called and tested separately.  In my case, perhaps I'm better off using OP's pattern from the question?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to approach this.

If the methods in `EvaluateService` don't need state, you could just use class methods, e.g.:

```
class EvaluateService
  def self.get_url
    # ...
  end
end

class CheckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url = EvaluateService.get_url
  end
end
```

In this scenario, `EvaluateService` should probably be a module.

---

If you want a single global `EvaluateService` instance, there's [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html):

```
class EvaluateService
  include Singleton

  def get_url
    # ...
  end
end

class CheckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url = EvaluateService.instance.get_url
  end
end
```

But global objects can be tricky.

---

Or you could use a helper method in your controller that creates a service instance (as needed) and memoizes it:

```
class EvaluateService  
  def get_url
    # ...
  end
end

class CheckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url = evaluate_service.get_url
  end

  private

  def evaluate_service
    @evaluate_service ||= EvaluateService.new
  end
end
```

Maybe even move it up to your `ApplicationController`.